# What is MaterialStateProperty<Color>?

Tags: flutter

What is MaterialStateProperty in ButtonStyle?

```
ThemeData(
  textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: , //?
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The purpose of `MaterialStateProperty` is to make it possible to specify different styles for different states.

[image: a button with different styles for different states]

For example, if we want a button that's usually blue, but turns green when it's pressed, and enlarges its texts at the same time, we can use `MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith` to do exactly that.

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
      // If the button is pressed, return green, otherwise blue
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
        return Colors.green;
      }
      return Colors.blue;
    }),
    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
      // If the button is pressed, return size 40, otherwise 20
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
        return TextStyle(fontSize: 40);
      }
      return TextStyle(fontSize: 20);
    }),
  ),
  child: Text("Changing Button"),
  onPressed: () {},
)
```

In addition to checking whether the button is being "pressed", `MaterialStateProperty` also supports: disabled, dragged, error, focused, hovered, pressed, scrolledUnder, selected. Note that it's possible to have multiple states at once. For example, a button can be both "disabled" & "hovered" at the same time. With `MaterialStateProperty` you can customize its appearance when that happens.

**"Okay, but I just want a red button."**

Sure, it seems like you can use: `MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red)` to make it red in all cases. But that's probably **NOT what you want**. For example, when the button is disabled, do you still want it to be red?

[image: a red button that's always red, even when disabled]

See, "all" means "all". This is not good.

So what, are we stuck dealing with `MaterialStateProperty` and checking for disabled states all day?

Thankfully, no. **There's a better way:**

If you are using `ElevatedButton`, you can use `ElevatedButton.styleFrom` as a base style. Similarly, if you are using `TextButton`, you can use `TextButton.styleFrom`. From there, you can easily modify some of the styles.

[image: a red button that can be properly disabled]

Code:

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
  child: Text("Red Button"),
  onPressed: () {},
)
```

That's it, you just pass in a `Color` class. Super easy, no `MaterialStateProperty` involved. And it automatically handles edge cases for you.

Comment: Very good answer. First time actually understanding it. Thank you for that.

Comment: It's unfortunate there isn't a "love" reaction to answers...  This would have gotten one, from me!

Comment: But plz change "primary" to "backgroundColor"! It's been deprecated.

Comment: (And I still really miss `RaisedButton()` and `FlatButton()`!... I always will.)

Comment: I don't mind that `MaterialStateProperty` exists for such a niche use case as the first example. What I do mind is having to use this overly verbose way of adding a color to a button. It's completely ridiculous. `styleFrom` is what most of us will end up using, but it's not something new users will know exists, so they'll end up using the verbose approach.

Answer (score 96):

I am assuming that you want to know how to assign a color to the backgroundColor parameter of the ButtonStyle widget. If that is the case then just type something like this:

```
backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
```

OR

```
backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Color(0xFF5D5F6E)),
```

Comment: This is horrible.

Comment: Even more horrible is getting the correct color based on your theme:

`backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary)`

Comment: Care to elaborate why this is horrible? Thanks!

Comment: @ubiquibacon you can set the background color once on the ButtonTheme in a Theme widget further up the tree rather than doing that every time inline.

Comment: @Chandler It's horrible because computer engineering is all about making complex topics simple. Adding a color to a button _should_ be simple. There's a workaround using the `styleFrom` methods, that's easier to work with.

Answer (score 36):

> Interface for classes that resolve to a value of type `T` based on a widget's interactive "state", which is defined as a set of MaterialStates.
> Material state properties represent values that depend on a widget's material "state". The state is encoded as a set of `MaterialState` values, like `MaterialState.focused`, `MaterialState.hovered`, `MaterialState.pressed`. For example, the `InkWell.overlayColor` defines the color that fills the ink well when it's pressed (the "splash color"), focused, or hovered. The InkWell uses the overlay color's resolve method to compute the color for the ink well's current state.
> `ButtonStyle`, which is used to configure the appearance of buttons like `TextButton`, `ElevatedButton`, and `OutlinedButton`, has many material state properties. The button widgets keep track of their current material state and resolve the button style's material state properties when their value is needed.

**Code Example:**

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Color getColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    const Set<MaterialState> interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
      MaterialState.pressed,
      MaterialState.hovered,
      MaterialState.focused,
    };
    if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
      return Colors.blue;
    }
    return Colors.red;
  }
  return TextButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('TextButton'),
  );
}
```

**A simple way to use it:**

```dart
MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green) // Whatever value you want
```

To get more you can check official [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html) of Material state properties made by the flutter team.

Comment: OHH you've provided us a very good answer, thanks for that!

Comment: Majority of this is copied from the [docs about MaterialStateProperty](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html), and it's not clear that it was. I suggest using `>` (quotation in markdown) when copying others.

Answer (score 6):

It is used to calculate the value depending on the current interactive state of the button, which can be hovered, pressed, focused,... ([full list here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialState-class.html)).

If you want a fixed value, you can use `MaterialStateProperty.all(YOUR_VALUE)`, this value will be applied to all button states.

You can find more information here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html

Comment: Is there any case where you would do anything different then this? If not, then why this horrible syntax?

Comment: Yes, when you want to set something like a color to the button depending on the state of the button, for example a color for normal state, another for hover state, another for pressed state, and so on... [Full list here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialState-class.html).
But for short and static code, use `.all` to apply the color to all of these states.