# The argument type 'EdgeInsets' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MaterialStateProperty<EdgeInsetsGeometry?>?'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add some padding to my widget but i am encountering this problem:

```
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 60.0),
  ),
  onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Text'),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [MaterialStateProperty](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html) allows you to pass a value that can depend on the state of a material widget (usually a [MaterialState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialState-class.html)).

As an example this can prove useful when a button needs to change its color or size when it is being pressed.

In your case using `MaterialStateProperty.all` as bellow should fix it.

```dart
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 60.0),
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Text'),
),
```

Its also worth mentioning this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66542199/what-is-materialstatepropertycolor).

Edit: [relevant video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CylXr3AF3uU) from the flutter channel

Answer (score 0):

You can create a final ButtonStyle and use in your button like:

```
final ButtonStyle raisedButtonStyle = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 60.0),
);

return Body(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[ 
      TextButton(
        style: raisedButtonStyle, 
        onPressed: (){},
        child: const Text("TEXT"),
      )
    ],
),);
```

https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons